# .msi file launched with java closes after a few seconds.

Tags: java, mysql, windows-installer

I am trying to launch MySql server installer which is in my resources folder but it terminates after a few seconds. However if I launch it manually it runs okay until the end. Below is my code.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    ClassLoader classloader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
                    String fileUrl = classloader.getResource("mysql.msi").getFile();
                    Runtime rf = Runtime.getRuntime();
                    Process pf = rf.exec("msiexec /i \"\\" + fileUrl + "\"");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // System.out.println(e.toString()); // not necessary
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        t.start();
```

Comment: What do you mean by MySql server installer, you should install server once and use it when needed, so you should start and stop it, you should not install it every time.

Comment: I have an installer file I want to launch with Java automatically, Never mind if it is MySQL or another application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it was just an advice, lets come to your case, Windows OS has certain set of security restrictions which allows only administrator to install or remove any application.

That is why, we see a promt window asking for Administrator password (or Admin's permission as YES/NO type, in case user has logged in as admin), and the promt screen is the heart of it's security, as it don't allow ANY OTHER APPLICATION TO HAVE CONTROL ON IT.

If you do a remote desktop via third party, you will never see the client machines promt screen (this is because of security constraints), so in your case, your java application is third party app which don't have enough permission to continue the operation further.

**Hence it closes after few seconds.**

How ever, you can start and stop already installed services by allowing permission once in your windows service control. So I was suggesting you to play with service only.

Comment: Thanks @Manoj for the advice, I have changed the my approach. Cheers

Comment: No problem @IsaacChambers :)